# multiple items add to database in c# windows form using entity framewrk

Tags: c#, database, winforms, entity-framework, desktop-application

I want to add multiple items to Database using entity framework from datagridview, but always get an error in the `SaveChanges()` method.

Here is my save button code

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in SaleGrid.Rows)
{
    var saleProduct = new SaleProduct
    {
        SalesId = Convert.ToInt32(txtInvoice.Text),
        CatId = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["CatId"].Value ?? DBNull.Value),
        CatQuiltyId = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["QualityId"].Value ?? DBNull.Value),
        SuitDesignId = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["DesignId"].Value ?? DBNull.Value),
        SaleType = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["TypeId"].Value ?? DBNull.Value),
        StockId = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["StockId"].Value ?? DBNull.Value),
        Price = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Price"].Value ?? DBNull.Value)
    };
    Db.SaleProducts.Add(saleProduct);
    Db.SaveChanges();
}

public partial class SaleProduct
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SalesId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CatId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CatQuiltyId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SuitDesignId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SaleType { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> StockId { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Comment: what is the error? please add error details into your question

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Comment: you need to include error details into your post by editing your question. And btw, please include `EntityValidationErrors` that is stated in your error

Comment: @MuhammadKaleem Can you add SaleProduct class to the question

Comment: SaleProduct Class added in the Question

Answer (score 0):

DbNull cannot be converted to Int32. If your value can be null then your Property is needed to be nullable.

```
public MyClass 
{
    public int? NullableProp {get; set;}
}
```

and your code

```
var saleProduct = new SaleProduct
{
     NullableProp = String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtInvoice.Text) ? (int)null :
          Convert.ToInt32(txtInvoice.Text),
     ....
}
```

---

Futhermore, It seems that you have ModelValidationError. In this case, you need to check `EntityValidationErrors` in order to understand what is exactly going wrong with your model.

Answer (score 0):

According to your error message it seems that some of your fields are possibly set as NOT NULL in database and you try to put NULL. You can check field EntityValidationErrors in your Exception in VS - there will be exact info which fields are incorrect

Comment: in Database there is only Primary key field is Nullable

Comment: As far as I am aware, Primary Key cannot be Nullable. Possibly in your model in c# property is set as not null and you try to put null in it. Have you checked EntityValidationErrors in your Exception in VS?

Comment: primary key is auto increment

Comment: What about EntityValidationErrors? Also could you add to question your table schema?

Answer (score 0):

You must first check null

```
row.Cells["Price"] is null ? DBNull.Value:Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Price"].Value)
```

Answer (score -1):

- Use This code and when the messages box show use

  ```
   ctrl + c
  ```
- To copy the message
- Then post it here

  ```
  try {

  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in SaleGrid.Rows)
  {
      var saleProduct = new SaleProduct
      {
          SalesId = Convert.ToInt32(txtInvoice.Text),
          CatId = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["CatId"].Value ?? DBNull.Value),
          CatQuiltyId = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["QualityId"].Value ?? DBNull.Value),
          SuitDesignId = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["DesignId"].Value ?? DBNull.Value),
          SaleType = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["TypeId"].Value ?? DBNull.Value),
          StockId = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["StockId"].Value ?? DBNull.Value),
          Price = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Price"].Value ?? DBNull.Value)
      };
      Db.SaleProducts.Add(saleProduct);
      Db.SaveChanges();
  }


  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    var messages = new List<string>();
    do
    {
      messages.Add(e.Message);
      e = e.InnerException;
    }
    while (e != null) ;
    var message = string.Join(" - ", messages);
    MessageBox.Show(message);

  }
  ```

Comment: thanks a lot . after try catch block i successfullly saved

Comment: @MuhammadKaleem How ?? did the Message Box  show up ?

Comment: @MuhammadElrashid Message box not show . but working fine

Comment: Please check this error occurs after your code.  validation failed for one or more entities. See entity validations errors properties for more details